# PhotoSwipe - How to make slideshow stop at last slide instead of going to next gallery

Tags: jquery, gallery, photoswipe, business-catalyst

I'm using PhotoSwipe on a page where I have four different galleries (Business Catalyst gallery modules, actually). When I open the gallery and click through the images, it doesn't stop at the end of that gallery but continues to the next gallery. I want the slideshow to stop at the last picture in the gallery so the user must close it to view the next gallery.

Comment: You need to post your code on here to get any kind of reply.  Try jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You need to set loop option to false when you are attaching the photoswipe. 
Like this:

```
Code.PhotoSwipe.attach(_Pictures, 
    {
        target: $('#carousel'),
        loop: false
    }
```